# await operator is being skipped

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, rxjs

Could you please help me with an issue I am facing?

I have attached my code below, after button click, it catches an error (if there is) but skips

```ts
await this.reloadGridsOnAction(contractItemSubSystemIDsList, responce, true);
```

Which means it just jumps to `catch (e)`.
I need it to reload my grid first.
Thank you for any advise.

```ts
private async onAssignClick() {
  this.isChangeAssociationInProcess$.next(true);
  const ac = this.activeContractCell$.getValue()!;
  const PostAwardContractID = getColumnValue(ac.record, PropNames.PostAwardContractID);
  const { contractItemSubSystemIDsList, ContractItemSubSystemIDsMap } = this.prepareUpdateLists(true);

  const body = {
    ContractItemSubSystemIDsList: ContractItemSubSystemIDsMap,
    PostAwardContractID,
    IsFromCWP: +(this.currentItemsModeId$.getValue() === ItemsMode.CWP)
  };

  try {
    await ModalSpinner.instance.show("Assigning", async () => {
      const responce = await ErrorHandler.executeWithHandling(() => HttpService.instance.post(assignmentsUrl, body).asJson<Array<{
        [PropNames.ModuleItemID]: number,
        [PropNames.ConstructionSubSystemID]: number
      }>>());

      await this.reloadGridsOnAction(contractItemSubSystemIDsList, responce, true);
    });

    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    if (!e.isConflict) throw e;
    const response = await (e.response as HttpResponse).asJson<any>(true);

    return ModalChannelService.instance.confirm(
      `ASSIGN ITEMS`,
      (
        <div className="delete-modal-content">
          <p className="modal-question">{response.Message}</p>
          <div className="distribution-board">
            <div className="text-ellipsis">Please refresh the page to see correct values.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ),
      [
        { returnValue: false, content: "CANCEL" },
      ],
      "assign-subsystems-modal"
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with rxjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it skips over your code like that, chances are it threw an error and went straight into the catch.

If you want to always execute this block

```
await this.reloadGridsOnAction(contractItemSubSystemIDsList, responce, true);
```

you might want to have a `finally` block after the `catch`.